# Ajax call to php - Undefined index error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Flow: main page -> ajax request on php(tester.php) -> json information back to main page.

I can't find a way around this error. Thanks

ajax call

```
$.ajax({
                url : "tester.php",
                type : "POST",
                //dataType : 'json',
                data : {
                    'lat':lat,
                    'lng':lng,
                    'year1':year1,
                    'month1':month1,
                    'day1':day1,
                    'year2':year2,
                    'month2':month2,
                    'day2':day2,
                    'category':category
                },
                 success: function(data)
                {
                    $.getJSON('tester.php',function(cost)
                        {
                            document.getElementById('userdensity').innerHTML = cost[0]+","+cost[1];
                            document.getElementById('advertising_cost').innerHTML = cost[2]+","+cost[3];
                        });
                });
```

Php:(tester.php):

```
<?
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];
$year1 = $_POST['year1'];
$year2 = $_POST['year2'];

$cost = array($lat,$lng,$year1,$year2);
echo json_encode($cost);

?>
```

Error:

```
[02-Mar-2015 21:02:35 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: lat in /Users/tester.php on line 2
[02-Mar-2015 21:02:35 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: lng in /Users/tester.php on line 3
[02-Mar-2015 21:02:35 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: year1 in /Users/tester.php on line 4
[02-Mar-2015 21:02:35 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: year2 in /Users/tester.php on line 5
```

Unsure where the error is. I have done this in the past and went well.

**Solution**: changed success to:

```
success: function(data)
                {
                    var info = $.parseJSON(data);
                            document.getElementById('userdensity').innerHTML = info[0]+","+info[1];
                            document.getElementById('advertising_cost').innerHTML = info[2]+","+info[3];
                }
```

Comment: In the success paramter why are you again calling $getJSON ?

Comment: Your `success` function is missing a closing `}`

Comment: Yes the error is happening because you are using $.getJSON which is sending a GET request to tester.php. There are no POST variables available on this second unnecessary request

Comment: Instead of calling `$.getJSON` use the `data` variable and parse it as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you're trying to get using getJson is already being returned by the AJAX call, so you can simply retrieve from the `data` variable returned. You can rewrite to something like this:

```
 $.ajax({
            url : "tester.php",
            type : "POST",
            //dataType : 'json',
            data : {
                'lat':lat,
                'lng':lng,
                'year1':year1,
                'month1':month1,
                'day1':day1,
                'year2':year2,
                'month2':month2,
                'day2':day2,
                'category':category
            },
             success: function(data){    
                response = $.parseJSON(data);                                       
                document.getElementById('userdensity').innerHTML = response[0]+","+response[1];
                document.getElementById('advertising_cost').innerHTML = response[2]+","+response[3];
            };
        });
```

Comment: This fixes the undefined index, however data[0] == '[', data[1] == '"' . Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you put a `console.log(data);` in the success callback?

Comment: Turns out: data == ["43.66203460000001","-79.42503199999999","2015","2015"]     data[0] == [ , data[1] == " , data[2] == 4 , data[3] == 3. How do i take string instead of character